# How can I change first items of a DataProvider?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cc

I have a datagrid with 5 columns and I want to manipulate its dataprovider. I'm trying to change dp's first column dynamically. I tried this:

```
for (var i:uint = 0; i < dp.length; i++) {
    var tempArr:Array = new Array(dp.getItemAt(i));
    tempArr[0] = String(i);
    dp.replaceItemAt(tempArr, i);
}
```

However this empties all cells in datagrid. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I fixed this.

```
for (var i:uint = 0; i < dp.length; i++) {
    dataGrid.editField(i, "noCol", String(i + 1));
}
```